# Guzzle not reading the body value

Tags: php, guzzle

I have this post request that can't read my $json_body. It gives me this error;

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function getBody() on null
```

I check my variables and it has a value, but once it goes to the post request its becoming null.

```
 $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, utf8_encode(API_KEY));

    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type'     => 'application/json',
            'Accept'           => 'application/json',
            'ACCESS_SIGNATURE' => $signature,
            'ACCESS_KEY'       => API_KEY,
            'ACCESS_NONCE'     => $nonce,
            'ACCESS_TIMESTAMP' => $timestamp,
        ],
        'body' => $json_body
    ]);
    var_dump($response->getBody()->getContents());die();
```

Is this an error from guzzle? Not sure. Please help, tried to look for answers but still got the same.

Comment: have you tried this request with postman?

Comment: I'm actually using Insomnia for. It's the same right? still gives me `Fatal error: Call to a member function getBody() on null`

Comment: I don't have experience with Insomnia. Basically you need to check whether the endpoint returns anything. There can be situations where requests die in the middle of execution without returning any headers. Then guzzle response will be null because it doesn't have enough info to return even an error

Comment: you are not getting any response, it may be due to response code, try to check if the statuscode is 200 or 201 then use getBody(), `if($response->getStatusCode() == 200){$response->getBody()->getContents()}`

Comment: also insomnia, postman any chrome extension to send http requests all are same

Comment: In OP's case the $response object is returned as NULL. Calling getStatusCode() on that object would just cause another Fatal Exception. The only way to handle this is by catching the exception.

Comment: @PrasadParadkar I am not saying to not use exception if anyone uses requestException as soon as the $response variable has any request exception to never reaches to next statement, it will go to the catch statement so if it doesn't reach to $response->getStatusCode() then it will never break.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response. I'm getting 202 status code. But when i try to use getBody() its null

Comment: this is resolved. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If $response is being reported as `null` that means that your POST request definitely failed. This could mean either a network issue or the API endpoint responding with a 4xx or 5xx level error.

To handle this you must wrap your request call inside a Try...Catch block. Here's how I do it...

```
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

$guzClient = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$params = ["headers" => [...], "body" => $json_body];

try {
    $req = $guzClient->request("POST", $url, $params);
} catch(RequestException $e) {
    // you can use $e to get more details on the failure. Ex- $e->getCode() returns the error code assigned by Guzzle to the exception.
    $req = $e->getResponse();
}

var_dump($req->getBody());
```

You can capture even more specific exceptions by replacing RequestException with those specific class names or by adding more Catch blocks. Please refer to [Guzzle's documentation here.](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#exceptions)

EDIT: Added a line to the top to use the RequestException namespace.

Comment: never heard a function called `getCode()`, do you mean `getStatusCode()`

Comment: Nope. I mean getCode(). Its a method in any Throwable object in PHP.

Comment: Ohh! I remember now, its ok, my bad went out of mind

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. I tried this and got the same error, undefined variable which is the getBody().

Comment: hi this is resolved. thank you for your help.